# Completed the game on Insanity but still miss the last achievement

Tags: mass-effect-3, achievements

So, I finished Mass Effect 3 on 'Insanity' difficulty and I got the achievement for doing so on the 360. But, the 'All the missions completed' achievement didn't trigger.

The thing is that I have connection problems some days with the internet and it obviously dropped out. I DID finish all the sidequest and every mission on Insanity, but, didn´t get the achievement.

Is it still possible to get it now? It was so damn hard to finish the whole game like that. I can´t imagine to start all over again.

Comment: i'm quite sure that when you let the credits roll you end up back on your ship just before you attack the Cerberus main base. unless there's a mission which was time sensitive (ie. missing which end/disappear after you to a particular Priority Mission or # sub mission) that you missed you shouldn't need to start from the beginning again

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, I will try that. Is a pain in the ass to start all over again. Thanks!

Comment: I recall there being a whole bunch of secondary missions not required to beat the game that went into the all missions completed trigger in mass effect.. *edit* confirmed. posting more info as an answer

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: Completing the single player game does not earn you the Unwavering achievement by itself, as you only have to complete half of the required missions in order to complete the game.**

I believe you are referring to the Unwavering achievement, for either completing all multiplayer missions with a gold rating, or completing all single player missions on the Insanity level of difficulty.

To complete the main story of the game, and in turn earn the achievement for completing the game on Insanity, you only need to complete the core story-related missions. However, there are several more missions that count towards the Unwavering achievement.

---

I checked out the [True Achievements listing for the achievement](http://www.trueachievements.com/a161843/unwavering-achievement.htm), since it has been so long since I played the game, and found its primary guide. It has a significant amount of upvotes, and very few downvotes, so I expect it to be very reliable.

---

It lists there being 13 story-related missions. However, there are 27 missions in total that count towards this objective. Counted missions are listed as "missions where you land on a planet/space station, do something and leave. The random fetch quests for Citadel people do not count."

I would expect the achievement is not unlocking because you simply have not earned it yet. Completing the single player constitutes less then half of what the achievement requires.

Answer (score -1):

You can just replay the last chapter again as long as you have the saves once your done you should get it.